# Reinstall Apache2, after remove on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have few errors with mysql-server, and after i tried more command in terminal, i don't find a proper way to resolve.

I decided to remove all (phpmyadmin, mysql, apache2).
Mysql and phpmyadmin, remove successfully, but i have problem with apache2..

For Apache2, i use this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
udo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
```

After that, i try install again apache2.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

But, localhost refused to connect.

In etc/hosts.conf is empty, what is necessary to add there?
Maybe, is possible to exist another problem?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me as well and I fixed it by:

1. uninstalling the package
2. $ whereis apache2
3. manually remove anything related to it
4. fresh package reinstall

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help! :) Can you offer more details about 4 step? (what command to use in terminal).

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2  --- installs apache2; if you need more info I need more info myself on what do you what to use it for, in order for me to know how to help you

Comment: Thank you again! I use apache2 for website host. I try your command in terminal, but i recive this error:  E:Unable to locate package apache2---installs .

Comment: sudo apt-get install apache2  ( --- installs apache2 was only the description of what it does, meaning it only installs the service)

Comment: it is the same line command you used originally to install the service. What do you intend to use apache for?

Comment: Oh, sorry for mistake. It works, thank you so much! I want to use apache for website host. Now i try install phpmyadmin and mysql service .

Comment: Good. No problem. 

PS: Bafta in continuare :D

Comment: Uh, multumesc tare mult :)) Now, when i try to install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql and php-mysql phpmyadmin, i recive: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-auth-mysql and php7-mysql. Do you have idea what can i do for solve this...?

Comment: Please write the full command line you have entered preceded by $ (example:     $ sudo apt-get install apache2 )

Comment: you might've tried to install outdated packages; some new ones are out there and include the old ones; try $ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: First time, i try to use sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php7-mysql phpmyadmin . I typed your command, but i revice: E: Package 'php5-mysql' haso no installation candidate . (Multumesc tare mult de ajutor, de azi dimineata tot ma chinui. Am programele functionale pe windows, dar sunt nevoit sa fac switch-ul pe Ubuntu, cu care din pacate nu am mai avut tangente si ma lovesc de tot felul de erori)

Comment: Actually, now i find a command to install php, and works. :) But, still have problems with phpmyadmin, when i try to install i receive:  Errors were encountered while porcessing: javascript-common libapache2-mod-php7.0 E: SUb-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1) and for that, i don't find a solution to solve.

Comment: I will try to get back at you tomorrow, as I have to respect the fact that is a Saturday night incoming :) Catch you tomorrow!

Comment: Oh, thank you so much and enjoy the Saturday! :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it works! :)

After install php, i typed in terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line to the end of the file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Thanks for help @Hellas and i hope this command  helps somebody!